# How to check in Apex if a Text field is blank

Tags: apex, string, isblank

I'm unsure what's the shortest and most robust way to check whether a Text field is blank / empty?

```
/*1*/ Boolean isBlank = record.txt_Field__c == '';
/*2*/ Boolean isBlank = record.txt_Field__c == null;
/*3*/ Boolean isBlank = record.txt_Field__c.trim() == '';
/*4*/ Boolean isBlank = record.txt_Field__c.size() == 0;
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I use the isBlank(String) method on the [string class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isBlank) in order to check whether a string is either null, white space or empty.

```
String.isBlank(record.txt_Field__c);
```

The documentation says:

> Returns true if the specified String is white space, empty (''), or null; otherwise, returns false.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is effectively a combination of 1 and 2 in @RobertSosemann's post as it catches both `null` and `''`.

Comment: and it would even catch strings with white space only like '   '.

Comment: Note: If checking from a query, pre- and post-whitespace is automatically trimmed, and if the result would be an empty space, the field is instead null. That means that you virtually never need to check for '' (empty string).

Comment: Thanks. It's like the difference between `String.IsNullOrEmpty` and [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#/.NET.

Comment: There are also isNotEmpty() and isNotBlank(), please check out the official docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Answer (score 13):

The difference is slight between `isEmpty()` and `isBlank()`

`isBlank(inputString)`: Returns true if the specified String is white space, empty (''), or null; otherwise, returns false.

`isEmpty(inputString)` : Returns true if the specified String is empty ('') or null; otherwise, returns false.

So the `isEmpty()` function is a subset of `isBlank()` function.

### **Usage**

In case, your check is for a null string or a string which does not contain any `value('')`, but in your usecase a String having a space is valid then use `isEmpty()`.

If you want to check if your string is null or have no value or have only blank spaces you should use isBlank

To know more about the String class you can follow the following link : **[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)**

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 6):

There's a method `isEmpty(String)`, which returns `true` if string is null or empty. Unlike `isBlank(String)`, returns `false` if string is white spaces.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
if(String.isBlank(record.txt_Field__c)){
    Boolean isBlank = true;
}
```

The above is same as:

```
if(record.txt_Field__c == null || record.txt_Field__c == '' || record.txt_Field__c.trim.length() == 0) {
    Boolean isBlank = true;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use this over the built in `String.isBlank`?

Comment: its better to use String.isBlank since it checks for all three conditions

Answer (score 0):

There are also `isNotEmpty()` and `isNotBlank()`, [check out the official documentation for String class in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)